# F String Returns on new line

Tags: python, f-string

I am building a song metadata library and the f string keeps returning a new line on the BPM String I added:

```
def all(self):
    return '{} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {}'.format(self.title, 
        self.length, 
        self.scale, 
        (f"{self.bpm} BPM"), 
        self.timesignature, 
        self.lyrics, 
        self.start, 
        self.end, 
        self.release, 
        self.album,  
        self.notes)
```

How do I keep the BPM string on the same line?

This is the output:

```
 Incunabula

 3:21
 C Aeolian
 69 
 BPM 4/4
```

BPM should be right after the 69.

Comment: Obviously `self.bpm` has a newline in it.

Answer (score 1):

As identified by @Selcuk, some of your strings contains whitespaces.

You can strip whitespaces (that includes newline) by using `str.strip()`. It removes surrounding whitespaces (before or after the string)

In your case, you can replace your BPM line (or any line that has whitespaces around it) with this.

```
...
(f"{self.bpm.strip()} BPM"), 
...
```